# Map<> type not suggesting autofill for union array

Tags: typescript

In the example below, why is typescript not giving autofill suggestion for "foo" or "bar" when typing elements into an empty array?

```
const map: Map<string, ('foo' | 'bar')[]> = new Map([
  ['hello', []],
  ['world', []],
]);
```

It is correctly showing error when something other than foo or bar is in the array but no suggestion, could this be a tsconfig problem or am i typing this Map incorrectly?

Comment: Move the generic to the constructor call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to initialize your `Map` with a generic:
`new Map<string, ('foo' | 'bar')[]>()`.

What you did was giving your `map` variable an explicit type. Use the generic constructor of `Map` and the type will be infered correctly automatically which means you won't need your explicit type anymore.

```
const map = new Map<string, ('foo' | 'bar')[]>([
  ['hello', []],
  ['world', []],
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are storing your Map to a typed map, but you are first of all creating a generic map. If you want to have typings when creating this map, you should also set the types to it accordingly like:

```
const map: Map<string, ('foo' | 'bar')[]> = new Map<string, ('foo' | 'bar')[]>([
  ['hello', []],
  ['world', []],
]);
```